# IOS NSDateFormatter Problems

Tags: ios, datetime, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter

We are building an app which requires the storage of a date for an entry on the device, the app will be international so we hit two dilema's / challenges.

1. User Preferences

   If the user chooses the 12 hour rahter than 24 hour format we are returned from [NSDate date] a date like this 2012-07-17 11:26:03 AM which for sorting in a SQLite database is less       than optimal as we cannot store it as a date.
2. User Locale

   Typically this is ok however here in blighty we have a wonderfult thing called british summertime. which adds one hour every October 25th - 30th in a cycle and removes one hour           every March 25 - 31th in a cycle so if no adjustment is made for 8 months of the year the time is one hour behind.

What I need to achieve is a consistent date formatted like this: 2012-07-17 11:26:03 no matter where the device is located and also taking into account where GMT+1 comes into place.

Any help would be awesome.

***EDIT****

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm";
NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT+01:00"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];
NSString *timeStamp = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSDate *localDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:timeStamp];


NSLocale* currentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale]; 
NSString* countryCode = [currentLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode];
NSLog(@"Country Code: %@", countryCode);
NSLog(@"Current Loacle: %@", currentLocale);
if(([countryCode isEqualToString: @"GB"])){
    NSDate *mydate = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *fiddlyFoo = [mydate dateByAddingTimeInterval:3600];
    NSLog(@"Print GMT +1 %@",fiddlyFoo); 
} else {
    NSLog(@"Print GMT Local   %@",localDate); 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm doing something like this now. Note that NSDate "knows" about the current timezone and daylight savings time etc. So you just need to get the GMT version of the time in a sortable representation. I'd suggest RFC 3339 but you can use variations on it per your needs:

This code:

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

// Create a local date for London, for testing purposes
NSDateComponents *comps = [NSDateComponents new];
[comps setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Europe/London"]];
[comps setDay:1];
[comps setMonth:7];
[comps setYear:2012];
[comps setHour:14];
NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];

// Just want to show this date is 2PM in London July 1st
NSDateFormatter *curFormat = [NSDateFormatter new];
[curFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
[curFormat setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
NSLog(@"Reference date is good no: %@", [curFormat stringFromDate:date]);

// So now we get the date as a rfc3339 string, referenced to GMT
NSString *timeString;
{
    NSDateFormatter *rfc3339 = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [rfc3339 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
    rfc3339.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
    timeString = [rfc3339 stringFromDate:date];
}
// referenced to UTC (sortable with any other time), can save in SQL DB etc
NSLog(@"Date as rfc3339 string: %@", timeString);

// Now lets convert it back into a BST time
NSDate *newDate;
{
    NSDateFormatter *rfc3339 = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [rfc3339 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
    rfc3339.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
    newDate = [rfc3339 dateFromString:timeString];

    // we want to show this as a string 2012-07-17 11:26:03
    NSDateFormatter *newFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [newFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]; // local time
    [newFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Europe/London"]];

    NSLog(@"Local string using 24 hour clock: %@", [newFormatter stringFromDate:newDate]);
}
```

Generates this output, which I believe is what you want:

```
TimeTester[58558:f803] Reference date is good no: Sunday, July 1, 2012 9:00:00 AM Eastern Daylight Time
TimeTester[58558:f803] Date as rfc3339 string: 2012-07-01T13:00:00Z
TimeTester[58558:f803] Local string using 24 hour clock: 2012-07-01 14:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks for this however when I conver the string back into a date i get the AM/PM appendix again which i need to stop. We need this as an NSDate as we are doing some stuff with it elsewhere in the app

Comment: Well, the above code gives you a representation that you can sort and which is GMT based. If you need to convert this into a string which you want to present to the user, then there is a reverse encoding that gives you a NSDate back - is that what you want?

Comment: My bad sorry my goal is just to get a 24 Hour date format back no matter what time zone or locale setting but have the adjustment for BST

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm dense, but if you save the time in UTC time in the database, once you have that you can use a date formatter to change that to any format you want. If you are doing this in real time on the phone, then you essentially probe iOS for the current timezone etc and apply it. If you are trying to do the conversion on an device but don't want to use the device's concept of current timezone, you can configure the formatter to use whatever timezone you want. I guess I just didn't quite understand what your goal is.

Comment: Look you gave me the answer but if you still don't get it then lets keep going. I can try to put something together using NYC time to better demonstrate what I was trying to say. I use the above technique in my app to first turn current time into a New York City current time, then later convert that string into a date shown to a person anywhere in the world. Its all working fine.

Comment: Thanks that would be great giving you the answer was as a thanks for helping thus far if you could put something together that would be awesome

Comment: Then you need to give me a really clear set of instructions. That is, there is an initial date that is stored - that date could be anywhere in the world. The date is converted to a string which is sortable, and I would imagine that it must sort against any other date from anywhere else, so what's sorted should be standardized (i.e. UTC). The later, you want to take that string out of the database and display it in this form "2012-07-17 11:26:03" - but is that day/time suppose to be in LOCAL time or UTC time?

Comment: OK so added some code. the goal: we need to capture a record date time stamp is in 24hour format e.g.. 2012-07-17 14:55:05 and store this in the local sqlite database the date time should be generated from the us users location, however in the uk we have BST which adds an hour to GMT for 8 months of our year the code above tries to deal with this.

What ever the users setting the date format saved and used needs to be 24 hour only.

Comment: See updated answer - if its not 100% what you want you should be able to figure out what to change.